# checking if 2 numbers of array add up to Input number in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby on rails .

I was programming ruby and want to try checking if 2 numbers of array add up to Input number in ruby.

eg,
array A[]= {3, 1, 8, 11, 5, 7}
given integer say N = 6
answer will be 1,5.

I know how to program it in java,C++ but i am stuck in ruby coding,

Can anyone please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should show the code you've written as you attempt to solve the problem, and explain why each attempt didn't work. Otherwise it appears you're simply fishing for someone else to write the code for you.

Comment: @theTinMan sorry for the question.Will remember it next time.Was caught up hence asked the question.Appreciate your comment

Comment: You can still do the work and update your question and it will likely be re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
ary = [3, 1, 8, 11, 5, 7]
n = 6
ary.combination(2).detect { |a, b| a + b == n }
#=> [1, 5]
```

- `combination(2)` creates an array of all combinations of length 2, i.e. `[3,1], [3,8], [3,11]` etc.
- `detect { |a, b| a + b == n }` returns the first pair with sum `n`

You can use [`find_all`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) instead of [`detect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) to return all pairs with sum `n`.

Comment: This solution is slow.

Comment: @sawa I'm trading speed for clarity ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [3, 1, 8, 11, 4, 5, 7, 2]
> a.combination(2).select {|i| i.inject(:+) == 6 }
#=> [[1, 5], [4, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [3, 1, 8, 11, 5, 7]
p a.combination(2).find{|i| i.inject(:+) == 6}
# >> [1, 5]
```